# Inefficient SQL on Login/Full table scan (UserStore.FindByNameAsync)

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

We are using Asp.Net Identity version 2.2.1 and EF 6.1.3 over an Oracle Database.

We do have an index on the usertable on UPPER(USERNAME) but still get full table scan on our user table for each user login.

The issue seems to be caused by this code in UserStore:

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
  this.ThrowIfDisposed();
  return this.GetUserAggregateAsync((
    Expression<Func<TUser, bool>>) (u =>
    u.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()));
}
```

this result in an SQL with

```
WHERE (((UPPER("Extent1".USERNAME)) = :p__linq__0) 
OR ((UPPER("Extent1".USERNAME) IS NULL) AND
    (:p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
```

and this OR part it seems is making the optimizer choose a full table scan.

When using SQL Server this may be optimized by changing the where statement to:

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
  this.ThrowIfDisposed();
  var uName = userName.ToUpper();
  return this.GetUserAggregateAsync((
    Expression<Func<TUser, bool>>) (u =>
    u.UserName.ToUpper() == uName));
}
```

and the where part is now :

```
WHERE N'<USERNAME>' = (UPPER([Extent1].[USERNAME]))
```

But I'm lost for options on how to optimize this when using Oracle. I have tried both Oracle.Managed driver and Devart.Oracle driver and they both generate where statements with OR when using UPPER function on a field.

It is a requirement to have CASE INSENSITIVE usernames in the database.

So why does EF generate a SQL with an OR statement when we use UPPER(field) = something?

Is there another way to pursue this? Does anyone have a good solution?

At this point our last option may be to make the username UPPERCASE in the data table and thereby avoid having to use the UPPER function - but it doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Comment: Have you tried - see my answer attempt

Comment: No.. `upper` is forcing the table scan. Putting a function around a column makes it non sargable (look that up)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, look up function based indexes. If OP has an index on 'upper(...)', as OP states, then it is sargable.

Comment: True - I didn't notice that part.

Comment: ErikEJ was spot on. This setting made EF create the SQL as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
context.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx